# Jquery: Changing placeholder text on hover, adding original text back following hover

Tags: jquery

I've created a section of text inputs which don't have the typical appearance (border). All have a placeholder attribute. When the user hovers over each input, I'd like the placeholder text to change. Once they move off the input area I would like that original placeholder text added back in. I have been successful in getting the alternate placeholder text in place while hovering, and I have attempted to add the original placeholder text back in by using the data method.

Markup:

```
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="Id Number" data-ph="Id Number">
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="First Name" data-ph="First Name">
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="Last Name" data-ph="Last Name">
Etc..
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.inline-edit').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'edit');
  });
  $('.inline-edit').mouseout(function(){
    var holder = $('.inline-edit').data('ph');
    $(this).attr('placeholder', holder);
  });
})
```

What is happening is that jquery is grabbing the first data attribute (data-ph="Id Number") and replacing the placeholder text with that value for all inputs.

Markup after hovering:

```
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="Id Number" data-ph="Id Number">
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="Id Number" data-ph="First Name">
<input type="text" class="inline-edit" placeholder="Id Number" data-ph="Last Name">
Etc..
```

I've searched far and wide and I can't find a similar situation with the exception of changing text on focus. From what I understand, the blur method won't help me in this task. I hope my explanation of the issue is clear and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at your `holder` variable.
It may work like this:

`var holder = $(this).data('ph');`

**UPDATE**

Or you can do something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.inline-edit').mouseover(function(){
    //gets the current placeholder
    this.holder=$(this).attr('placeholder');
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'edit');
  });
  $('.inline-edit').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', this.holder); //sets it back to the initial value
  });
})
```

There's no need to use another inline attribute.

**IMPORTANT** to avoid further issues consider using `$.focus()` and `$.blur()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The issue was the variable. I did try the full function you wrote as well but that did not work. Thanks again -

Comment: Your right I was replacing the same attribute `this.placeholder=$(this).attr('placeholder');` change the var name and it should work just fine. `this.holder=$(this).attr('placeholder');`